# Build kernel driver with Windows SDK 10.0.20348 - no more ntoskrnl.lib?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to build a Windows kernel driver with the new Windows SDK 10.0.20348, but the build cannot find 10\lib\10.0.20348.0\km\x64\ntoskrnl.lib:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\km\x64\ntoskrnl.lib'
```

Is ntoskrnl.lib no longer supported in 10.0.20348, or do I miss something else ?

WinSDK 10.0.19.041 still has that library:

```
$ find /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ -iname ntoskrnl.lib -ls
281474977350513    836 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     852788 Dec  1  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.19041.0/km/arm/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977350489    768 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     783006 Dec  1  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.19041.0/km/arm64/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977347929    820 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     839508 Dec  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.19041.0/km/x64/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977348046    872 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     892218 Dec  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.19041.0/km/x86/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349408    668 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     682044 Nov  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/win7/km/x64/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349328    704 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     719922 Jun 23  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/win7/km/x86/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349511    712 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     728936 Jun 20  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/win8/km/arm/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349615    644 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     655438 Nov  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/win8/km/x64/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349633    672 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     687918 Jun 23  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/win8/km/x86/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349751    732 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     746102 Jun 20  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/winv6.3/km/arm/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349955    664 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     679632 Nov  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/winv6.3/km/x64/ntoskrnl.lib
281474977349835    736 -rwxr-x---   1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM     752656 Dec  2  2020 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/winv6.3/km/x86/ntoskrnl.lib
```

Comment: Should be there, my install of 10.0.22621.0 has the file.

Comment: are you install wdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling WDK can fix it.

[image]

Please install **[WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk#download-icon-step-3-install-wdk)**.

Select the version you need.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-2-install-the-wdk